# Many adjacent polygons, want to convert polygons to paths and remove resultant duplicate paths

Tags: json, path, border, polygon, overlap

I have a json file with 80ish adjacent counties, represented as individual polygons. Each county, as expected, shares borders with other counties.

I'd like to convert each of those polygons to paths, creating paths symbolizing the borders of every county. At this point, I'd be left with many overlapping or duplicate paths where counties shared borders.

I'd like to find a systematic way to delete these overlapping paths so each line representing a border is only displayed once. By doing so, I'll be able to style the borders individually to fix a problem described in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045679/overlapping-dashed-dotted-strokes-on-adjacent-paths-in-svg).

Does such a thing exist? I'm aware of the possibility of deleting shared borders in Illustrator, but many of the county polygons share borders with 3+ other counties, making this incredibly tedious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I eventually tackled this problem using ArcMap. My steps:

1. Create a shapefile from the json I was using and load into ArcMap
2. Import the shapefile into a geodatabase
3. Put the file into a feature dataset
4. Create a topology (right click on Feature Dataset > New > Topology)
5. Add a rule to the topology against overlapping lines
6. Find all errors (overlapping lines)
7. Use the error inspector to select each overlapping line and Subtract (right click on error) one of the lines
8. Took me about 5 minutes to do remove a hundred or so.